# find minimum of one variable and matching values of other variables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I create a test data set using the following commands in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
   (v1 INT,
   v2 INT,
   v3 INT);

INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(1,3,300);
INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(1,2,200);
INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(1,1,100);
INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(2,9,900);
INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(2,7,700);
INSERT INTO test (v1,v2,v3) VALUES(2,5,500);
```

I want to find the minimum of v2 while grouping by v1 and to display the value for v3 matching the minimum of v2.  In other words:

```
v1 v2 v3
1  1  100
2  5  500
```

When I run the following:

```
SELECT v1,MIN(v2),v3 FROM test
    GROUP BY v1;
```

I get:

```
v1 v2 v3
1  1  300
2  5  900
```

How do I get the desired output?

Comment: what if you group by v1 and v3, same problem?

Comment: No, I only get one line after adding v3, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sub query should work fine in this case. You can try something like below:

```
Select v1, v2, v3 from test a
where (select min(v2)
from test b
where a.v1 = b.v1) = v2;
```

Comment: Thanks, although I don't understand how the subquery uses the 'a' table when the number of rows in 'a' hasn't been decided.